# update_post_meta not saving empty value - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

I am trying to remove a post meta value. This is my code:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'gcal_event_id', '' );
```

It's not saving. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_post_meta), there is also a `delete_post_meta` function that is used for removing post meta values.

Passing the third argument deletes only the meta values that equal the one provided. If you want to remove *all* of a post’s meta values for the given key, omit the third argument.